# How to import binary file into R as a nx1 array

Tags: r, matlab, import

I am trying to import some raw data files (unknown file type) from an MIT facial recognition project site. The files each contain a 16384x1 array of pixel values for a 128*128 image of a face.

Here is the site with the data:

http://courses.media.mit.edu/2004fall/mas622j/04.projects/faces/

Raw data is provided in an unknown file format (some sort of .bin or .dat, I'm really not sure), and should encode for a 16284X1 array.  I have tried reading in the files with readBin(), which results in a 4096x1 array (code shown below, "1227" is the file name). In addition, the values of this array have a huge range (min=-2139063177, max= 2139781749), which does not allow them to be pixel values with image().

```
data<-readBin("1227", "integer",n=128*128, endian = "big")
```

Changing endian to "little" results in a array of length zero. I had a friend try to read the file in matlab, and they were successful with the following code:

```
fid=fopen('rawdata/1223'); 
I = fread(fid);
imagesc(reshape(I, 128, 128)'); colormap(gray(256));
```

The files are available at the link I posted above, but let me know if I should post the contents of one the files to be read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data appear to be an array of bytes which code for a greyscale value. You can read the data into R and plot it with

```
xx <- matrix(as.numeric(readBin("1223", "raw", 128*128)), ncol=128, byrow = TRUE)
plot(as.raster(xx, max=255))
```

which will return

[image]